# How can I remove pending downloads in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, applications

I have an update for the Dexter game on iPhone which is 400MB in size. Since I don't play this game anymore, I deleted the app. But iTunes still wants me to download the update and tells me I have "1 iTunes Download available".

I tried deleting it (pause then *right-click*-*delete*), but the download keeps coming back.

Is there a way to permanently remove those available downloads?

Comment: Have you tried logging into the iTunes store and hiding the app in your account before deleting it?

Comment: Is that something you could always do? I thought it was something new (or is it only the fact that you can now also do it on iOS?). But no, I didn't tried that at the time.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't look at the date of the question until you pointed it out. It is new.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is there a **Downloads** item in the Store area of the column on the left side of iTunes? If so then you can click on it, click on the stalled download, and delete it.

**Edited to add**

There are a couple of places you might check after quitting iTunes. The first is

```
/Users/yourUserName/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications/Downloads/
```

Make sure it's empty, and if not, remove what's in there (set it aside so you can put it back if it confuses iTunes later).

The other place is:

```
/Users/yourUserName/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications/
```

and look for the file `Dexter.ipa` (or `DexteGame.ipa` or whatever the game is called). Delete this file -- it's the actual now-outdated game that iTunes is trying to update.

Otherwise iTunes has the need to download it stored in its database and doesn't care about files.

I take it that agreeing to the download doesn't help?

Comment: Did that. The download keeps coming back.

Comment: I added a couple of suggestions to my answer. If those don't work and accepting the download doesn't work then the only thing I can think of isn an iTunes wipe (after backing up all of the iTunes content) and reinstall.

Comment: A much simpler solution (to wiping iTunes, +1 for your answer above which is detailed and good) is just to let the thing download and then delete it, assuming you're on broadband.

Comment: @msa I thought of it too. That'll be my last resort.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as accepted, even though I had to download it -twice-.

Comment: BIG UPS to @MatthewFrederick!!!!!! There are not words to describe how angry I've been even looking at iTunes the last month!!!

Comment: "Let the thing download and then delete it" was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: I recently had this problem and for whatever reason, the only way I could get it to work now was to let it download and then delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the file,
Slide slowly to the left on the download icon until you see a Delete button in a red box.

Try it few times if it doesn't work.

Comment: Your caps lock is on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue w/ two apps that I did not want to download. I finally downloaded both apps and then deleted them.